# The routing behavior of VMs in Azure is strange

Tags: routing, azure, subnet

I have three Ubuntu machines, machine A, B, C. 
I also created a VNet 10.3.0.0/16, and create three sub-net SubN1: 10.3.0.0/24 SubN2: 10.3.1.0/24 SubN3: 10.3.2.0/24

Machine A has 3 nics, eth0, eth1, eth2 
Machine B has 2 nics eth0, eth1 
Machine C has 2 nics eth0, eth1

I let eth0 of every machine connect to SubN1 for management purpose.
Machine A eth1 and Machine B eth1 belongs to SubN2
Machine A eth2 and Machine C eth1 belongs to SubN3
I want to let Machine B connect to Machine C with interface eth1, It means I need to add a route between Machine B & C
I've verified B and C not connected.

Then, In machine B routing table, I type the command:
 ip route add {SubN3}/24 via {Ip address of Machine A's eth1} dev eth1 
In machine C routing table, I type the command: 
 ip route add {SubN2}/24 via {Ip address of Machine A's eth2} dev eth1

I even didn't set the IP forwarding in Machine A, then machine B can connect to machine C via their eth1 successfully.

It's great! However, the questions come.

I cannot see any traffic in Machine A(either eth1 or eth2) while Machine B and C are connected(ping or ssh each other)

Even I shutdown Machine A. Machine B and C are still connected!!, It is weird.

What I want is: machine B and C connected but the traffic should via Machine A.

Would you tell me what's wrong or anything I need to set?

Thanks

Comment: What default gateway does each host use? If you shut down A, what does a `traceroute` between B and C look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for more time for the ping output.

I have the same test as you.

```
vm1 has nic0 10.0.0.4, nic1 10.0.1.4, nic2 10.0.2.4;
vm2 has nic0 10.0.0.5, nic1 10.0.1.5;
vm3 has nic0 10.0.0.6, nic2 10.0.2.5.
nic0s join into subnet0 10.0.0.0/24; 
nic1s join into subnet1 10.0.1.0 24; 
nic2s join into subnet2 10.0.2.0/24.
```

Then I add the one route to vm2: `sudo ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 via 10.0.1.4 dev eth1`
[image]

add one route to vm3: `sudo ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.2.4 dev eth1`
[image]

So I can ping from vm2 to vm3 using eth1. Once I stop the vm1 on the portal. I find the response: Destination Host Unreachable.
[image]

Once I restart the vm1, The ping connection is restoring.
[image]

So I think you set correct, just need more time in this case.

Comment: Please let me know if this helps or if you need more info in this case.